# SCSS: On hover div, show another div

Tags: html, css, reactjs, sass

I'm trying to show the elements in another div when hovering over a div. This is what I have now, and it's not working. Currently, it just doesn't do anything on hover, it is just non-responsive. Any tips would be greatly appreciated. I am not using any other languages such as JQuery. Thank you!

**HTML/React**

```
<div className="parent">
    <div className="show-me">
        <Element />
    </div>
    <div className="hover-me">
        <span>hi</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**SCSS:**

```
.parent {
    .hover-me {
        @include icon('help', inherit);
        color: $b500-blue;

        span {
            font-weight: 700;
        }
    }

    .show-me {
        .show-me-body {
            opacity: 0;

        }
     }

     .hover-me:hover ~ .show-me .show-me-body {
         opacity: 1;
     }
}
```

The below answer works, but I could not get it to work with the element I have inside show-me.
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your HTML as follows, it will work. `.hover-me` should come before `.show-me`.

`~ Selector:` The `.hover-me ~ .show-me` selector matches occurrences of `.show-me` that are preceded by `.hover-me`.

```
 <div className="parent">
      <div className="hover-me">
           <span>hi</span>
       </div>
       <div className="show-me">
           <Element />
       </div>

  </div>
```

Working snippet

```css
/*COMPILED CSS*/

.parent .hover-me {
  color: red;
}
.parent .hover-me span {
  font-weight: 700;
}
.parent .show-me .show-me-body {
  opacity: 0;
}
.parent .hover-me:hover ~ .show-me .show-me-body {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
      <div class="parent">
            
            <div class="hover-me">
                <span>hi</span>
            </div>
        <div class="show-me">
              <div class="show-me-body">Hellow</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! The above answer works, but does not work when I replace show-me-body div with the element I have. Above are the attachments of the styles associated to the element I have

Comment: I got it by setting pointer-events to none